# AWS Lambda error when adding a layer for snowflake-connector-python package

Tags: python, aws-lambda, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aws-lambda-layers

I am trying to implement a python lambda function that would connect to a Snowflake database. To do that, I need to create a layer for snowflake-connector-python, so I create a zip package of this layer on my Jenkins pipeline, which runs in an Ubuntu Linux container, python 3.10:

```
mkdir -p ./python
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install snowflake-connector-python -t ./python
zip -r snowflake-connector-python.zip ./python
```

I upload this to my Lambda via terraform:

```
resource "aws_lambda_layer_version" "lambda_layer" {
  filename            = "${path.module}/../snowflake-connector-python.zip"
  layer_name          = "snowflake"
  compatible_runtimes = ["python3.8"]
}
```

This works and I can see my layer added in my lambda upon deployment:
[image]

The problem is that when I try to import this library in my lamda by doing a `import snowflake.connector`, I get the below error:

> "Unable to import module 'lambda_function1': No module named '_cffi_backend'"

I have verified that if I change my package to `requests`, it compiles succesfully, so it seems to be OS specific C components inside snowflake-connector-python that is causing the issue.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Can you add a step in the installation for `sudo apt-get install -y libssl-dev libffi-dev` before installing Snowflake Python connector?

Comment: @Sergiu thanks, but I was able to resolve this by making my layer name the same as my package name, `import snowflake.connector`